# Expectation value through spectral theorem in s-f Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, greens-functions, second-quantization

The model that i am studying is the s-f model.

I wrote some post about it, then, in order to understund better my notation go to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526275/problem-with-a-commutator-involving-the-s-f-hamiltonian?)

Now, I am computing some parameters that emerge out of the equations of motion for the Green's function.

For this purpose i am using the spectral theorem
$$
\left\langle
\hat{B}\,\hat{A}
\right\rangle
=
\frac{1}{\hbar}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\,
\text{d}E
\,
\frac{S_{\hat{A}\,\hat{B}}\left(E\right)}{e^{\beta\,E} + 1 }
$$
Since i know the Green function i can compute the spectral density through
$$
 \text{Im}\,\text{G}_{\hat{A},\hat{B}}^{r} \left(E \right)
=
-\,\pi \,\text{S}_{\hat{A},\hat{B}}\left( E \right)
$$

The parameter that i have to found is 
$$
\Delta^{-\sigma}_{i}
=
\frac{1}{\hbar}
\left\langle
\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}
\,\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}\,\hat{a}_{i,-\sigma}
\right\rangle
-
\frac{1}{\hbar}\,
 z_{\sigma}
\left\langle
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}\,
\hat{n}_{i,-\sigma}
\right\rangle
\tag{1}
\label{eq:1}
$$
where $\hat{a}_{i,\sigma},\,\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}$ are the fermionic operators referred to the conduction electrons, $i$ is the index of the $i-th$ lattice site while $\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow$ the spin number.

$\hat{S}^{z}_{i}$ and $\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}$ are the spin operators referred to the isolated electrons in f-shells.

They commute to each other because they belong to different degrees of freedom of the system

I computed a Green function that could be used for this purpose 
$$
        \ll
\hat{d}_{i,\sigma}; \,
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}\,   
        \gg
\equiv
G_{d,\sigma}^{r}\left(E\right)
$$
where 
$$
\hat{d}_{i,\sigma}
=
z_{\sigma}\,
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}
\,\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}
+
\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}
\,\hat{a}_{i,-\sigma}
$$
so the spectral theorem could compute the following correlation function
\begin{align}
        \left\langle
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}\,   
\hat{d}_{i,\sigma} 
        \right\rangle 
        &=
                \left\langle
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}\,   
\left(
z_{\sigma}\,
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}
\,\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}
+
\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}
\,\hat{a}_{i,-\sigma}
\right)
        \right\rangle 
        \\
                &=
                z_{\sigma}\,
 \left\langle
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}\,
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}
\,\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}
        \right\rangle 
+
 \left\langle
\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}
\,\hat{a}_{i,-\sigma}
        \right\rangle 
        \\
        &=
                       z_{\sigma}\,
 \left\langle
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}\,
\hat{n}_{i,\sigma}
        \right\rangle 
+
\left\langle
\hat{S}^{-\sigma}_{i}
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}
\,\hat{a}_{i,-\sigma}
        \right\rangle  
\tag{2}
\label{eq:2}
\end{align}

I noticed that changing the spin index of \eqref{eq:2} from $\sigma$ to $-\sigma$

\begin{equation}
       \left\langle
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,-\sigma}\,   
\hat{d}_{i,-\sigma} 
        \right\rangle 
        =
 -  z_{\sigma}\,
 \left\langle
\hat{S}^{z}_{i}\,
\hat{n}_{i,-\sigma}
        \right\rangle 
+
 \left\langle
\hat{S}^{\sigma}_{i}
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,-\sigma}
\,\hat{a}_{i,\sigma}
        \right\rangle  
\tag{3}
\label{eq:3}
\end{equation} 
and summing \eqref{eq:2} and \eqref{eq:3}, i have the following relation
\begin{equation}
       \left\langle
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}\,   
\hat{d}_{i,\sigma} 
        \right\rangle 
+
    \left\langle
\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{i,-\sigma}\,   
\hat{d}_{i,-\sigma} 
       \right\rangle 
=
 \hbar\,
\left(
\Delta_{i,\sigma}
+
\Delta_{i,-\sigma}
\right)
\tag{4}
\label{eq:4}
\end{equation}
in \eqref{eq:3} i used the propieties of $z_{\sigma}$. Since it could be 1 or -1 , it satisfies
\begin{align*}
z_{\sigma}\cdot z_{\sigma} &= 1 \,\forall\,\sigma \\
 z_{-\sigma} &= -z_{\sigma} \,\forall\,\sigma
\end{align*}
The rhs of \eqref{eq:4} is computed through the spectral theorem. knowing that 
$$
S_{d,\sigma} = \hbar^{2}\,\sum_{i=1}^{4} \, \beta_{i,\sigma}\,\delta\left(E - E_{i} + \mu\right)
$$
where $\beta_{i,\sigma}$ is the i-th spectral weight referred to the i-th excitation energy $E_{i}$, while $\mu$ is the chemical potential

Then \eqref{eq:4} becomes 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{4}\,\left(\beta_{i,\sigma} + \beta_{i,-\sigma}\right)
f_{i}\left(T\right)
 = 
\Delta_{i}^{\sigma}
+
\Delta_{i}^{-\sigma}
\tag{5}
\label{eq:5}
\end{equation}
where 
$$
f_{i}\left(T\right) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta\left(E_{i} - \mu\right)}}
$$
Unfortunatly i have not a relation only for the parameter \eqref{eq:1}

The result of the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642091063)  is 
$$
\Delta_{i}^{-\sigma}
=
\sum_{i=1}^{4}\,\beta_{i,-\sigma} 
f_{i}\left(T\right)
$$
but i can't find other relations that allow me to find this one.

I can't use directly the spectral theorem for the spectral density related to $S_{d,-\sigma}$, beacuse it does not reproduce the correlation function \eqref{eq:1}

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms in title.

Comment: Which ones? You said it in the previous question too, but i don't know which acronyms you mean